# Difference between the two types of FCM push notification payloads (notification vs data) and when do they arrive to Android FirebaseMessagingService?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In Firebase push notifications, the payload can be of type "notification" or "payload", but they arrive (or not) depending on whether the app is in background or not and other details. Please clarify them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(This answer focuses on Android devices)

Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) push notifications can be of [three types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) : notification, data and notification+data.

- **Notification** messages are meant to be received by the Android operating system itself, with no intervention by the app. When received by Android, they will be shown as a notification in the tray. Some details:

  - The tray notification will not be shown if received when your app is in the foreground.
  - You can implement a FirebaseMessagingService (see the data payload for more info on this), which will receive the message if your app is in the foreground. In your FirebaseMessagingService, you can show a tray notification yourself (or do whatever you want) when you receive the message.
  - When sending the message, you can specify what happens when the user clicks on the notification; this can be controlled by either specifying an activity in the `click_action` Android-specific option (see [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#example-notification-message-with-platform-specific-delivery-options)) or by specifying an URL in the `link` property and having your app configure an [intent filter](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) associated with the URL you specified.
- **Data** messages are meant to be received by an [Android service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) of your app. This service can, in principle (see below [*]), receive the messages when your app is in the foreground, in the background, or not running at all. Some details:

  - To implement the service, you have to extend [FirebaseMessagingService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService) and configure it in your app's manifest.
  - When you receive the message in your FirebaseMessagingService, you can decide to emit a local notification to be shown in the tray. You can do this either when your app is in the background or in the foreground, in principle (see below [*]). Of course, you may also decide to do other stuff instead (or apart) of showing the tray notification.
  - [*] Some phone manufacturers, especially Chinese ones like Xiaomi and Oppo, implement some mechanisms to save battery that include killing services. This means that, by default, your FirebaseMessagingService will not be running on those phones unless your app is on the foreground and, therefore, **it will NOT receive your data payloads when your app is not on the foreground**. There is no way around this, except if the user whitelists your app specifically. The famous apps like Whatapp or Gmail are by default included in the whitelist, but yours won't; therefore, if you rely on data payloads and you want your app to work on that kind of phones, you'd better guide your user to configure their phone to allow it; [here](https://c.mi.com/thread-1416749-1-0.html) you can see how to do it for Xiaomi (Miui) devices. This can also happen in vanilla Android devices since [Android 9 (API level 28)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#restricted) with [background restrictions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services), but the behaviour is opposite: your service won't be killed unless the user requests it; you can check this with [ActivityManager.isBackgroundRestricted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#isBackgroundRestricted())
- **Notification + data** messages include [both types of payloads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messages-with-both-notification-and-data-payloads). They behave exactly like notification payload-only messages:

  - When your app is in background, Android shows the notification in the tray. The `data` payload is accessible to the app if it receives the intent invocation when the user clicks (described above) in `intent.extras`.
  - When your app is in foreground, your FirebaseMessagingService receives the notification with the contents of the data payload.